# Differencing and trend in time series forecasting

Tags: forecasting, arima, data-transformation, trend

I understand that a time series is differenced to remove trend. But if trend can be modeled for forecasting purposes then why difference a time series at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You difference the trend in pure time series models such as ARIMA. However, there are many approaches which take care of the non-constant trend without necessarily differencing. For instance, consider ARIMAX model:
$$y_t=c+\beta t^2+\phi_1 y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$
Here, you have the nonlinear trend $t^2$ and as typical autoregressive term $y_{t-1}$. This is just one approach of many possible

Comment: You do not difference a deterministic time trend in pure time series models because that would create a unit-root MA(1) component. (Or actually, some people who are not aware of the problem do that, to the extent that this can be considered a notorious bad habbit. The problem is called *overdifferencing*.) You only difference stochastic time trends.

Answer (score 2):

If trend can be modeled, why difference a time series at all? That is a good question! The answer is, you do not difference the series in such instances.

You only difference series that contain stochastic time trends, i.e. series that are cumulative sums of stationary processes (I we restrict ourselves to processes with a single unit root). You do not difference a time series that does not have a unit root, e.g. a time series with a deterministic time trend. Such series are called trend stationary. Differencing such a series creates a unit-root MA(1) component which, if neglected, messes up estimates of the other parameters in the model. This problem is called *over-differencing*.

Comment: Thank you that helps alot that always confused me. So for the versions of the Dickey Fuller test that include trend is this a deterministic trend?

Comment: @MichaelHowell, there are versions with *drift* and *trend*. *Drift* means a linear trend in data in levels, $ct$, while *trend* means a quadratic trend in data in levels, $ct^2$, where $c$ is a constant and $t$ is a time index.

Comment: I think the point made above, that you only difference stochastic trends not deterministic ones is a critical point and one not covered well in the literature. The first step with trends is to determine if they are deterministic or stochastic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what method you use if you difference. To cite an obvious example some methods such as exponential smoothing do not require (or use) this. It is an assumption (a requirement) of ARIMA that you difference non-stationarity, but not all time series methods.

Comment: Thank you that is a good point.