# Forecast the trend, differencing practices

Tags: time-series

If I have a time series problem, and I want to forecast the trend. Should I then bother with removing the trend to ensure stationarity? I use linear regression to train and predict.

I read this related post, where the concept "trend stationary" is mentioned.

[Differencing and trend in time series forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408379/differencing-and-trend-in-time-series-forecasting)

A concept that is elaboarated upon here in the following link using an example of gdp.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/trend-stationary-vs-difference-stationary.html

Should differencing be used in modeling when you have a time series with features with a gdp-like-trend?

Comment: Do you want to forecast the trend, e.g. know what the trend is in the future? Or do you want to make a forecast? Is the goal machine-learning (e.g. 'just get me a predictor!') or inference (e.g. 'what is the slope, and how certain am I about it?'). what have you tried and what did you think about the result you got with that approach?

Comment: @LudvigH The aim is to make forecast of the trend and based on that say something on the state of economy the coming year. I'm interested in general reasoning and theoretical foundation of how to transform a time series when you forecast data with a lot of "natural" trend like gdp.

Comment: Trend removal is about ensuring that the statistical assumptions for inference are met Those assumptions depend on the model (that you choose). The trend to remove depends on the data (which you can never have certain knowledge about). There is no simple answer that adresses your question fully. I suggest you make the question more specific by e.g. naming a model, point to a specific dataset, show you attempted analysis and so on.

The general topic about when differencing helps in analysis is interesting, and I'm very much interested in the potential answers to your question.

Comment: I elaborate later today here.   :)